# postfix reject_unverified_recipient auto retry?

Tags: postfix, spam

We have an postfix SMTP server, used to relay mail for customers web scripts. 
Postfix is using [recipient address verification](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_VERIFICATION_README.html) with `reject_unverified_recipient` in `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` (it is a must, due to high number of unwanted bounces otherwise):

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = 
    reject_unknown_recipient_domain
    reject_unverified_recipient
    permit_mynetworks
    reject_unauth_destination
    check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/validrcptto
```

Problem is that first time some e-mail address is used, it will result in `450 4.1.1 <xxx@example.com>: Recipient address rejected: unverified address: Address verification in progress` temporary errors, which client is supposed to retry later (as defined in section *4.5.4.1* of [RFC 5321](http://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc5321))

While the `4xx` error is gone in few seconds (in vast majority of the cases, or replaced with `5xx` permanent error), the customers web scripts (of course) try only once.

While it is relatively trivial to implement in web scripts (replace `SEND_MAIL` with `while (count++ < 10) { SEND_MAIL; sleep(3) }` pseudo-code), the number of different customers, third-party codebases with its auto upgrades etc) just explaining the problem over and over again is prohibitively resource-draining...

What I would like is something like `reject_unverified_recipient_after_autoretry=30s` which would not reply immediately to `RCPT TO` with `450 Address verification in progress` but would instead block, waiting a few seconds in hope [verify(8)](http://www.postfix.org/verify.8.html) will finish, and try again, and only return `450` if after (say) 30 seconds the code is still `450`.

Note: accepting all mails from web scripts is not acceptable (even if sender is set to `<>` or some unattended/blackholed mailbox) - we really want address verification, and we want web apps to get `5xx` errors if we can know the mail won't be able to reach recipient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it eventually, the needed options (not mentioned in `verify(8)` manpage) are:

```
 address_verify_poll_count = ${stress?1}${stress:6}
 address_verify_poll_delay = 5s
```

This will wait on `RCPT TO` for [address verification](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_VERIFICATION_README.html) to finish for 6 iterations of 5 seconds (so up to 30 seconds) before returning `450 4.1.1 <xxx@example.com>: Recipient address rejected: unverified address: Address verification in progress` error (Under high load it would try only once).
Of course, if address verification finishes sooner, it will return sooner.

So exactly what I needed!

Options are available in Postfix 2.1 and later